# Nginx FastCGI Caching possible on custom URL's?

Tags: nginx, cache, fastcgi

I am trying to build a custom caching solution for my website with FastCGI caching.

I'm trying to cache only certain URL's that get a boat load of traffic. I know from my logs exactly which URL's that are, but they are always changing.

Is there a way I can specify certain URL's that Nginx has to cache, but not cache everything else.

I've followed [this tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-setup-fastcgi-caching-with-nginx-on-your-vps), and I got caching to work. But I cannot work out how to cache custom URLs. Say url.com/b.php?q=123 for example.

Ideally I would store a list of URL's in a .conf file, which Nginx loads, and it only uses cache for those URL's, but doesn't cache all other files. Is this possible with Nginx?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a `map` for this. Place it in a separate file which is `include`d from the server's `http` block, and then whenever it changes, reload nginx.

An example:

```
map $request_uri $my_no_cache {
    default           1;
    /b.php?q=123      0;
}
```

To use it, place this in the relevant `server` or `location`:

```
fastcgi_no_cache $my_no_cache;
fastcgi_cache_bypass $my_no_cache;
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I just tried this setup, but got an error. I made a file cache_map.conf to include in the http block. But doing a configtest run, it show: nginx: [emerg] "map" directive is not allowed here in /etc/nginx/cache_map.conf:1

Comment: That happens if you include it from the wrong place. It has to be directly within the `http` block, not within a `server` block.

Comment: My bad, just noticed that! Error is gone now. It's not caching some how, but I'm gonna keep bug hunting.